# Delta Lake on EMR and Zeppelin gives 'configure_spark_with_delta_pip' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I am trying to use Delta lake on Zeppelin running on EMR. Below is my simple bootstrap script, I am using spark-delta 0.0.1 as spark version on EMR is 2.4.4. When I try to create spark session in notebook I below exception.

> > Fail to execute line 7: spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-2848864742877081666.py", line 380, in 
> > exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
> > File "", line 7, in 
> > NameError: name 'configure_spark_with_delta_pip' is not defined

I also tried adding `delta-code_2.11-0.6.1.jar` before creating the session but not luck and got below exception (shown in screenshot).

> > module 'pyspark.sql.utils' has no attribute 'convert_exception'

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Upgrade pip

python3 -m pip uninstall botocore --user
python3 -m pip uninstall boto3 --user


sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

python3 -m pip install botocore==1.13.38 --user

sudo yum -y install python3-devel

python3 -m pip install keras==2.2.4 --user

python3 -m pip install numpy==1.19.1 --user


sudo python3 -m pip install pyarrow
sudo python3 -m pip install boto3
sudo python3 -m pip install torch
sudo python3 -m pip install scipy 
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas
sudo python3 -m pip install delta-spark==0.0.1
```

[image: When I add delta-code jar as addPyFile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.0.1` is a test version to verify pip release process. It's not a real release. You should use 1.0.0 or above based on your Spark version. You can find the compatibility matrix in the [doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html#compatibility-with-apache-spark).

```
sudo python3 -m pip install delta-spark==1.0.0
```